# how to make graphic timelines in mathematica

Tags: graphics, date-and-time

Hi does anyone know how to make timelines with mathematica?

[image]

Something like that would be great!

Comment: Interesting ... but sounds like a convoluted requirement for Mma. Why don't use a hammer [if you gotta nail a nail](https://www.google.com/search?q=timeline+software)?

Comment: @belisarius I think it's a reasonable task for *Mathematica* with some potentially interesting solutions.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Perhaps it may rise interesting answers, but under a concise and real requirement a pragmatical mindset is better, I think. If there are good and free solutions, why bother to roll your own? Unless you are doing some HW, which I think is not the case here.

Comment: This is clearly doable, and not very difficult, but it's a lot of work.  It's much more likely that you'll get an answer if you first try to implement it on your own, show us what you have, and ask about the specific point you got stuck at.

Comment: In agreement with Szabolcs I would suggest you try out on your own first. Look up the documentation for Graphics, Line and Text, it's really just a task of combining these depending on your input list.

Comment: Also, `Inset` and `Panel` would be good to look at.

Comment: right-o. i had a feeling i would be pointed to the primitive graphics like line etc. i'll get right on it and let you know what i got

Comment: [This presentation](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7467/dan_martinez_presentation.nb?file_id=7096), _Dynamic Timeline Plots_, by Daniel G Martinez, may be of interest.

Comment: Can't you just do Insert --> Picture --> New Graphic?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I tried to do something similar a few months ago

The easiest way is to write several functions:

---

EventFrame function creates event lables

```
EventFrame[str_, {date_, height_}, OptionsPattern[FontSize -> 14]] := 
Graphics[{
  Black, Thick, Line[{{date, height}, {date, 0}}], 
  Text[Framed[Style[str, FontSize -> OptionValue[FontSize]],
  {Background -> White, FrameStyle -> Black,FrameMargins -> Automatic}], {date, height}]
}]
```

DateConv converts date {yr,mon,day} into single real number

```
Needs["Calendar`"]
LeapYearQ[year_] := DateQ[{year, 2, 29}]
DateConv[y_, m_, d_]:=y+(DateDifference[{y},{y, m, d}]+1)/If[LeapYearQ[y], 366, 365]
DateConv[{y_, m_, d_}]:=y+(DateDifference[{y},{y, m, d}]+1)/If[LeapYearQ[y], 366, 365]
```

TimeLine function creates timeline

```
TimeLine[min_, max_] := 
Graphics[{ 
  (* TimeLine *)
  Black, Thick, Line[{{min, 0}, {max, 0}}], 
  (* year ticks *)
  Thin, Table[Line[{{x, 0.5}, {x, 0}}], {x, min, max}],
  (* year labels *)
  Table[Text[Framed[Style[x, FontSize -> 20],
  {Background -> White, FrameStyle -> White}], {x, 1}], {x, min, max}]
}]
```

Now all we need is a `Show` function.
Use `Pane` for for easier viewing

```
Pane[Show[
    EventFrame["Event 1", {DateConv[1988, 6, 2], 4}],
    EventFrame["Event 2", {DateConv[1990, 8, 15], -2}],
    (************************)
    TimeLine[1985, 1995],
    (************************)
     AspectRatio -> 1/6, ImageSize -> {1400, 280}],
    (************************)
    ImageSize -> {550, 280}, Scrollbars -> {True, False}]
```

Output without `Pane`
[image]

**Edit**

`EventFrame2` function

```
EventFrame2[str_, {date_, height_}, OptionsPattern[{FontSize -> 14, offsets -> {0, 0}}]] := 
Graphics[{
  Thick,Line[{{date, height}, {date, 0}}], 
  Text[Framed[Style[Column@{Style[ToString[Floor[date]],
  Bold,TextAlignment -> Left], str}, 
  FontSize -> OptionValue[FontSize]],
 {Background -> White, FrameStyle -> Black,FrameMargins -> Automatic}],
{date, height},OptionValue[offsets]]
} ]
```

Example

```
EventFrame2["Event 1", {DateConv[1988, 6, 2], 4}, offsets -> {-0.97, -0.5}]
```

[image]

---

**Update 2014 - Mathematica 10**

`LeapYearQ` is now a standard Mathematica function.

`DateDifference`now returns Quantity[n_,"Days"]

New `DateConv` function:

```
DateConv[y_, m_, d_] := 
 y + (DateDifference[{y}, {y, m, d}][[1]] + 1)/If[LeapYearQ[y], 366, 365]
```

Comment: Does this handle leap years? The division by 365 in `DateConv` makes me wonder.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about that. Added LeapYearQ function

Comment: Instead of `DateConv[]`, you might consider the use of `AbsoluteTime[]`...

Comment: this is fantastic. some ideas i'm going to try to implement: tooltip for difference between dates, title and eventually tagging. my original idea was to have certain events with tags like :

event 1 - green tag, red tag, yellow tag;
event 2 - green tag; 
event 3 - red tag;

when red tag is selected only events 1 and 2 are displayed. in that vein. will begin work and modifications tonight

Comment: what exactly does the second DateConv[] function do? 

`DateConv[{y_, m_, d_}]:=y+(DateDifference[{y},{y, m, d}]+1)/If[LeapYearQ[y], 366, 365]`

Comment: it doesn't do anything here, but if you have list of dates, you can do `DateConv[#]& /@{{y1,m1,d1},{y2,m2,d2},..}`

Answer (score 15):

[image]

Based on data in Comm ACM. This took a while to *only* partially automate, largely through a helper function that spreads out the years:

```
diffuse[a_][years_List] := 
  Module[{x0 = 1, x1 = Length[years], y0 = Min[years], 
    y1 = Max[years]},
   years // 
    MapIndexed[ {#1, (((y1 - y0)/(x1 - x0))*(First[#2] - x0) + 
           y0) a + (#1) (1 - a)} &]];
```

`diffuse` maps a list of time points and spreads the interor points. The parameter `a` in principle can be any real number but higher values in [0,1] correspond to increasingly uniform spacing.

is defined in op form for use in `Dataset`:

```
data = {<|"Year" -> 1906, "Author" -> "Markov", "Contribution" -> "Markov theory"|>, <|"Year" -> 1907, "Author" -> "Perron","Contribution" -> "Perron theorem"|>, <|"Year" -> 1912, "Author" -> "Frobenius", "Contribution" -> "Perron-Frobenius theorem"|>, <|"Year" -> 1929, "Author" -> "von Mises", "Contribution" -> "Power method"|>, <|"Year" -> 1941,"Author" -> "Leontief",  "Contribution" -> "Econometric model"|>, <|"Year" -> 1949,  "Author" -> "Seeley", "Contribution" -> "Sociometric model"|>, <|"Year" -> 1952, "Author" -> "Wei", "Contribution" -> "Sport ranking model"|>, <|"Year" -> 1953, "Author" -> "Katz", "Contribution" -> "Sociometric model"|>, <|"Year" -> 1965, "Author" -> "Hubbell", "Contribution" -> "Sociometric model"|>, <|"Year" -> 1976,  "Author" -> "Pinsk, Narin",  "Contribution" -> "Bibliometric model"|>, <|"Year" -> 1998, "Author" -> "Kleinberg", "Contribution" -> "HITS"|>, <|"Year" -> 1998, "Author" -> "Brin, Page", "Contribution" -> "PageRank"|>} //Dataset;
```

Some years cluster:

```
data[All, "Year"] // Normal // NumberLinePlot
```

[image]

Make interpolation function (alternatively, can define an Association)

```
shift = data[
  GroupBy[#Year &] /* Keys /* diffuse[0.35] /* Interpolation]
```

Values `a ~ 1/3` work for this particular data and graphics w/ coorindated shift:

```
itemGraphics := {{Darker@Blue, Disk[{#Year, 0}, 0.25]},
   {Thickness[0.001], Opacity[0.5], 
    BezierCurve[{{#Year, 0}, {#Year, 2}, {shift[#Year], 
       1 + 3/4}, {shift[#Year], 1 + 3/2}, {shift[#Year], 3}}]},
   Text[Column[{Style[ToLowerCase@#Author, Darker@Blue, 
       FontSize -> 14, Bold], 
      Style[ToLowerCase@#Contribution, Small]}, 
     Spacings -> 0], {shift[#Year], 4}, {-1, 1/2}, {1, 1}, 
    BaseStyle -> None]} &
```

Layout w/o timeline shows label clashing :

```
data[Graphics, itemGraphics]
```

[image]

```
data[GroupBy[#Year &]][Values, 
   MapIndexed[Translate[#1, {0, 6 (First[#2] - 1)}] &], itemGraphics] // 
  Normal // Graphics[{#}, Axes -> {True, False}, 
   PlotRange -> {{1900, 2020}, All}, 
   TicksStyle -> Directive@{FontSize -> 15, Darker@Blue}, 
   ImageSize -> 1000, ImagePadding -> 50] &
```

[image]

At `a=0.7` balloon lines are stretched and spacing is more even but many labels are shifted way off past the years of future events.

[image]

This illustrates the interaction of `ImageSize`, `AspectRatio`, fonts, and data content (time clustering, ties, label dimensions (no easy way to get bounding boxes) seriously complicates automating layout.

Comment: Pardon me, but how is this supposed to be used?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, you can similarly ask of many system functions, like how is `BarChart` supposed to be used in the real world when it never does exactly what you want. In any case added methods.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, btw, the Brin & Page baloon line ideally would curve around Kleinberg, but then that graphic component would have to be refactored one `Level` up. Also there's likely more modular approach naming and processing graphics in Associations.

Answer (score 15):

As of Mathematica 10.1, creating a timeline is built-in with [`TimelinePlot[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimelinePlot.html).

```
TimelinePlot[{
    Labeled[Interval[{DateObject[{2010, 2, 1}], DateObject[{2013, 5, 4}]}], "label1"], 
    Labeled[DateObject[{2012, 4, 6}], "label2"], 
    Labeled[Interval[{DateObject[{2011, 3, 1}], DateObject[{2012, 12, 21}]}], "label3"]
  }]
```

[image]

Lots of possibilities, looking at the documentation!

```
TimelinePlot[EntityClass["Movie", "BackToTheFutureFranchise"] -> "ReleaseDate"]
```

[image]

Comment: As of 10.1 `TimelinePlot` doesn't have a robust layout engine. For example try to display all disasters from here http://www.airdisaster.com/cgi-bin/database.cgi, the labels crowd on top of each other so they become unreadable  - this can only be avoided by selecting subsets or extreme `AspectRatio`. Compare to GIS layout engines like Google Maps, where stree names may disappear on zoomout, but don't crowd each other.