# Problems with TimelinePlot

Tags: plotting, date-and-time

I'm trying to play with the example in [this recent blog post](http://blog.wolfram.com/2015/03/11/new-in-the-wolfram-language-timelineplot/), but I'm having a few basic issues with `TimelinePlot`:

1. Labels are getting cut off:
   [image]
2. How can I get labels to go above and below a timeline in `TimelinePlot` just like in the following example?
   [image]

Answer (score 4):

I cannot quite manage what you want: the labels keep getting cut off when placed below the image. However, placing the labels to the right of the image does very well.

```
data = EntityValue[EntityClass["Movie", "StarTrekFranchise"],
 {"ReleaseDate", "Image", "Name"}];

movieInfo = #1 -> Labeled[ImageResize[#2, 40], #3, Right] & @@@ data;
```

Note the entity query above; it gathers all the information from the server with a minimum of calls.  Now, with the right options, this can be made quite nice

```
TimelinePlot[movieInfo, AxesOrigin -> Center, PlotLayout -> "Grouped"]
```

[image]

`PlotLayout -> "Grouped"` does not do much here as several of the other layouts do the same thing, but it does a trigger different layout algorithm which works better in tight groupings.

I also like the vertical style

```
TimelinePlot[movieInfo, PlotLayout -> "ReversedVertical",
  AxesOrigin -> Center]
```

[image]

The "Reverse" is needed to have the axis ascending, not descending, and not the lack of "Grouped".

Comment: thanks, with PlotLayout -> "Grouped"] the arrows go underneath the labels and it's hard to see which goes where, is there some option to make them use bezier curves or something to make the lines go around the labels?

Comment: @M.R. that's effectively what the default does, but it clusters the labels which isn't useful here. I'll play with and see.

Comment: @M.R., I don't think currently `TimelinePlot` has a true layout engine. For a roll your own, see for example my answer to http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6802/how-to-make-graphic-timelines-in-mathematica

Comment: @alancalvitti I think you are right.

Comment: @alancalvitti I'm not sure what you mean by a "true layout engine" even after reading your previous post.

Comment: @rcollyer, I describe this in a comment to this Q and by contrast to Google Maps - http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78377/801