# How to change size of item in TimelinePlot?

Tags: plotting

How can one change the size of the markers in the `TimelinePlot`:

```
tp = {{2014, 12, 29} -> 
    ImageResize[ ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], 600], {2015, 12, 
     14} -> ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}]};

TimelinePlot[tp, Spacings -> 10, AspectRatio -> 1/4, 
 AxesOrigin -> Center, PlotLayout -> "Grouped", 
 ImageSize -> {500, Automatic}, GridLines -> {Automatic, None}, 
 PreserveImageOptions -> True]
```

[image]

After checking all the options and examples in the documentation it's still unclear how to control this. I'm not sure if I should be using `ImageResize`, `Item`s like in `Grid`, `Tooltips`, etc...

And simply using a `Panel` breaks everything:

[image]

**Related:**

- [Problems with TimelinePlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80394/problems-with-timelineplot)
- [how to make graphic timelines in mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6802/how-to-make-graphic-timelines-in-mathematica)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `Panel` and `Pane` work with just the `PlotLayout` option.

```
tpp = {{2014, 12, 29} -> 
    Pane@ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], 700], {2015, 
     12, 14} -> ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}]};

TimelinePlot[tpp, PlotLayout -> "Grouped"]
```

[image]

However, something is odd as simply adding an empty string `PlotLayout` option (`PlotLayout -> ""`) also works. Bug, perhaps?

Hope this helps.

version 10.3.1 on Win Pro 8.1 64bit

Comment: Also "AspectRatio -> 1/4" seems to break the sizing.