# Include Images in Timeline Mathematica

Tags: graphics, date-and-time

I'd like to include an image in a timeline in mathematica.

Is this possible using the `TimelinePlot`? There is [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6802/how-to-make-graphic-timelines-in-mathematica) previous question which considers graphical timelines, but nothing that will create a timeline that has images and a title at each dates.

Any advice on where to start to look for a solution?

Comment: Can you post some example data? It's hard to know if you mean eg images in the legend or tooltip.

Comment: Also check out `PlotMarkers`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an example of images in a TimelinePlot

First, set the image variable to your image
[image: copied screenshot of this question]

Second, create data for the plot using rules

```
data = { {2017, 10, 02} -> image, {2018, 10, 02} -> image}
```

Then use TimelinePlot

```
TimelinePlot@data
```

The result

[image]